# Suppress Application not responding message

Tags: windows, delphi

I am having Delphi windows application running in Windows Server 2008 R2, which will initiate request to windows service to populate data. While performing this task, application will become busy with the not responding message on the application title bar. At this time if we close the application, application will terminate with out displaying any message "the application is not responding. The program may respond again if you wait "

But the application running in Windows server 2016 is showing "the application is not responding. The program may respond again if you wait" while closing the application.
[image: Application not responding]

Can anyone suggest how to suppress this message with no code change and allow user to close the application if he wants to close?

disableProcessWindowsGhosting; code is not supposed to include in the application.

Comment: This is why threading was invented.

Comment: Don't fix the symptom, fix the root cause. That is, put the heavy work into a thread, and make sure the work can be aborted.

Comment: unfortunately, it was a legacy application and there is no code with us. until now this application was in Windows Server 2008 R2 and now we have migrated to 2016 server. I am looking for any server level changes which makes application behavior same as 2008 Server.

Comment: Familiarize yourself with the Windows Messaging system. Then research multithreading. Then you will learn that what you want to do is impossible without code. That message is pretty self-explanatory - your application isn't responding to Windows (likely it's stuck doing a big task), and so Windows throws that message on it.

Answer (score 3):

You have two main options:

1. Call [`DisableProcessWindowsGhosting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-disableprocesswindowsghosting). This is not a great option in the sense that it suppresses the problem rather than solves it.
2. Move the long running task into a worker thread and thereby allow your main thread to service the UI. This is the best practice solution.

Comment: unfortunately, it was a legacy application and there is no code with us. until now this application was in Windows Server 2008 R2 and now we have migrated to 2016 server. I am looking for any server level changes which makes application behavior same as 2008 Server

Comment: This site, Stack Overflow, is for programming questions.

Comment: @D.VenkataNaresh As far as I know there is no possibility to surpress this mesage wihtout editing application code.

Comment: @D.VenkataNaresh "*I am looking for any server level changes which makes application behavior same as 2008 Server*" - there is no such option. *Every* application in *every* Windows version suffers from this issue, this is nothing specific to 2008 vs 2016. If an application does not stay responsive to the OS, the OS will complain about it, usually in some visual manner for the user to see. If you can't update the code for the legacy app, then replace the app, or just live with the warning message. Those are your options.